# Jquery each function removing active classes from all elements

Tags: jquery

I have 4 blocks and I am running a `each` function to switch active classes on click but I cant seem to figure out how to target the specific block I'm clicking it will just remove the `active` class on all elements.

Here is my current code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="dashboard__block">
    <div class="dashboard__title">
      <b>Number Of Orders</b>
      | Total: 1000
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__date">
      <a class="black-link previous">Yesterday</a>
      <a class="black-link current active">Today</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__data">
      200
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="dashboard__block">
    <div class="dashboard__title">
      <b>Number Of Orders</b>
      | Total: 1000
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__date">
      <a class="black-link previous">Yesterday</a>
      <a class="black-link current active">Today</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__data">
      200
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="dashboard__block">
    <div class="dashboard__title">
      <b>Number Of Orders</b>
      | Total: 1000
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__date">
      <a class="black-link previous">Yesterday</a>
      <a class="black-link current active">Today</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__data">
      200
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="dashboard__block">
    <div class="dashboard__title">
      <b>Number Of Orders</b>
      | Total: 1000
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__date">
      <a class="black-link previous">Yesterday</a>
      <a class="black-link current active">Today</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard__data">
      200
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$('.dashboard__block').each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this).find("a").click(function() {
    // remove classes from all
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `removeClass()` in parent element context, which can be target using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('.dashboard__block').on('click', 'a', function () {
    //Target dashboard__block then target anchors
    $(this).closest('.dashboard__block').find("a").removeClass("active");
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Additionally, You don't need `.each()` to bind event handler

Answer (score 0):

The loop is your problem.

Remove the loop and catch the onclick event.

Hence:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dashboard_block a", function() {
    (".dashboard_block a").removeClass("active"):
    $(this).addClass("active")
    });
```

Also possible is to do

```
$(".dashboard_block a:not(this)").removeClass("active")
```

within the onclick event if the clicked element already has an active class

Answer (score 0):

Parent is faster than it closest but only select one above

```
$('.dashboard__block').each(function(i, obj) {
      $(this).find("a").click(function() {
        // remove classes from all
        $(this).parent("div").find("a").removeClass("active");
        // add class to the one we clicked
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    });
https://jsfiddle.net/Qh0stM4N/rss9ercz/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the sibling `<a>` element using `siblings('a')`, then `addClass('active')` back on the clicked `<a>`:

```
$('.dashboard__block').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5rvsL2c/)